# iOS - How to load only certain elements of a UIWebView to load page faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, uiwebview

I need to figure out a way to only load certain elements of a page. I don't need any images and probably 90% of the whole page, just a couple of interactive buttons and such. If a specific example is needed, I need to only load things like the add to cart button on a nike.com page

Comment: I doubt `UIWebView` can control the loading sequence.

Comment: as per my knowledge .. A WebView can load the complete webpage without our interference if you are using HTML code then you will have an option of coding the HTML as per your requirement...

Comment: @CharanGiri is right. `UIWebView` does not provide any method to reload a part of page. Better you have to design your own `HTML` page and use `AJAX` for reloading a part of web Page.